# Postgresql get list of rows from last update statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

How can i get a list of rows that were updated with last UPDATE statement?

for example :

```
UPDATE test SET title = 'dont delete this' WHERE id IN(1,2,3);
UPDATE test SET deleted = true WHERE id NOT IN last_updated_rows('id');
```

Also, is there a way to do a query like this in single update statement?

Comment: Use `RETURNING` clause to get the necessary information from updated rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `returning` clause specifically does what you want.  But the queries in your question could be handled with logic like this:

```
UPDATE test
    SET title = (case when id in (1, 2, 3) then 'dont delete this' else title end),
        delete = (case when id in (1, 2, 3) then delete else true end);
```